# Symmetry in Analytic Continuation of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-x E_n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, analyticity, analytic-continuation, analytic-functions

Suppose we have the following function:

$$F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-x E_n}$$

Where $E_n$ is a positive monotonically increasing sequence, bounded from below. Is there a general condition on $E_n$ such that the function and it's analytic continuation symmetric in x? For example, consider $E_n=n+1/2$. Then:

$$F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{- x(n+1/2)}=\frac{1}{2 \sinh\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)}, x>0$$

When analytically continued to $F(-x)$, this is clearly symmetric in x and odd. Are there any other such examples?

Comment: i assume you calculate boltzmann wheights $x\sim 1/k_bT$?

Comment: yes, but the mathematics is the same with $x$

Comment: so $E_n$ is bounded from below...

Comment: Yes, and it's also positive. I've added that to the problem description.

Comment: Your function seems not to be analytic for $\Re z = 0$, so your analytic continuation is not exactly an analytic continuation: it will be defined on a disconnected set, so you may choose to give it any value for $\Re z < 0$, in which case your nice symmetry is not required to hold.

Comment: $1/\sinh(x)$ is not analytic only on a few points on the imaginary axis.